# Is there any way out to solve this multiple conditional groupby with aggregation with pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, pandas-groupby

I am stuck with this complex groupby on multiple condition it would be really grateful if you could help?

Input Dataframe :
[image: Input Dataframe]

and I Need something This kind of Output:

[image: OUT put]

Now I need groupby based on every unique_ID and where I get IF_Car_with_History == 1 I need Sum of value in every row and mean of amount the same raw

Now I am Trying to solve this with this code which is taking time :

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,120789,"2012-07-03",0,1000,500]\
    , [1,232101,"2015-05-06",1,2300,700]\
    , [1,329911,"2016-05-19",1,4000,1000]\
    ,[2,129088,"2011-01-01",0,1200,400]\
    , [2,876541,"2013-03-01",1,1000,600]\
    , [2,864347,"2014-05-03",0,3000,1000]\
    , [2,987659,"2015-01-01",1,3200,700]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns =["Unique_ID","Transaction_ID","Date","IF_Car_with_History","Value","Amount"])
for i in data.Unique_ID.unique():
    df=data[data['Unique_ID']==i].reset_index(drop=True)
    idx=df[df['IF_Car_with_History']==1].reset_index()['index'].tolist()
    for s in idx:
        tmp=pd.DataFrame()
        hpa = df.iloc[s]["Transaction_ID"]
        tmp=df.iloc[:s]
        T_no = tmp["Transaction_ID"].iloc[-1]

        # print(tmp.columns)
        tmp=tmp.groupby(['Unique_ID'],as_index=False)\
         .agg(Value= ('Value','sum')\
               ,Amount= ('Amount','mean')).reset_index(drop=True)         
        # print(tm2)

        tmp["T_no"] = 0        
        tmp["T_no"][0] = T_no
        tmp["HPA"] = 0 
        tmp['HPA'][0]=hpa
        test_df = test_df.append(tmp)
```

This code snippet is taking a long time. Is there any better solution for this ?

Comment: kindly share data not pics

Comment: @sammywemmy I added the data as well. Thanks

Comment: @jezrael If you can help me here. It would be really great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, group by `Unique_ID` and `IF_Car_with_History` and then find `sum` and `mean` of `Value`, and concatenate the values of `Transaction_ID`:

```
df['Transaction_ID'] = df['Transaction_ID'].astype(str)
print(df.groupby(by=['Unique_ID', 'IF_Car_with_History'], as_index=False).agg(
    {'Amount': ['sum'],
    'Value': ['sum', 'mean'],
    'Transaction_ID': ', '.join,
    }))
```

**Output**:

```
  Unique_ID IF_Car_with_History Amount Value        Transaction_ID
                                   sum   sum  mean            join
0         1                   0    500  1000  1000          120789
1         1                   1   1700  6300  3150  232101, 329911
2         2                   0   1400  4200  2100  129088, 864347
3         2                   1   1300  4200  2100  876541, 987659
```

Comment: Thanks @NYC for your response but my expected output is different.